# Finding a group with minimal generators and then a subgroup generated by these as an index two normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, gap, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a group with seven generators and seven relations, each of length 3, how can I use GAP to find the group generated by only three of its generators?

For example,

$$G = \langle a,b,c,d,e,f,g \mid abc, abd, acd, bef, cge, dfg, egf\rangle.$$

Furthermore, How can I then find an index two normal subgroup $H$ of this and the relations of $H$?

I'm trying to explore if some particular groups that are presented in *"Star Graphs, Projective Planes and Free Subgroups in Small Cancellation Groups"* by Edjvet & Howie can have a mixed Beauville structure.

I have this so far for the group above.

```
F:=FreeGroup(7);; a:=F.1;; b:=F.2;; c:=F.3;; d:=F.4;; e:=F.5;; f:=F.6;; g:=F.7;; 
rels := [abc, abd, acd, bef, cge, dfg, egf];; 
G := F/rels;; 
S:=SimplifiedFpGroup(G);
epi:=EpimorphismPGroup(S,2,3);;
img:=Image(epi);;
G23:=Image(epi); 
Size(G23); 
IdGroup(G23);
List(PCentralSeries(img),Size);
```

The idea is to take a group G and find a maximal 2-quotient of class 3 of that group, say S.  Then similarly, I need a 2 indexed normal subgroup of S, let's call it H, that is is also a maximal 2-quotient group of class 3.

I need to find both S and also the presentation of H to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want GAP's help here? In this example, it is easily done by hand.

Comment: Are you able to explain how please?

Comment: Of course, but your question is currently a Problem Statement Question and needs improved. So for example tell us where it came from or what you've tried.

Comment: you should edit this context into the question. Is this specific group in their paper?

Comment: @user1729 - Yes this group is in the paper.

Comment: This is very unclear. Is H a subgroup of G? Of S?  What is *the8 (so is it unique?) subgroup generated by three of its generators?

Comment: I vote to close, because of a carelessly written question: The group as given does not have any 2-quotient. The GAP code is is syntactically incorrect in describing the relators. And I think the presentation is copied wrongly from the paper. (I suspect the second relator should be $adb$, not $abd$)

Answer (score 2):

Using GAP here is overkill - we can do it by hand.

Firstly, we can use [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) here to find a presentation of $G$ with only *two* of the given generators (and $2<3$). I mentally worked out that this could be done easily because any of the first three relations can be used to remove $a$, while $bef$ can be used for $b$, $cge$ for $c$, $dfg$ for $d$ and $egf$ for $e$. However, in the following working I spotted a few more obvious moves which I did instead.
\begin{align*}
G &= \langle a,b,c,d,e,f,g \mid abc, abd, acd, bef, cge, dfg, egf\rangle\\
&\cong \langle a,b,c,d,e,f,g \mid a=c^{-1}b^{-1}, abd, acd, bef, cge, dfg, egf\rangle\\
&\cong \langle b,c,d,e,f,g \mid c^{-1}b^{-1}bd, c^{-1}b^{-1}cd, bef, cge, dfg, egf\rangle&\text{remove $a$ generator}\\
&\cong \langle b,c,d,e,f,g \mid c^{-1}d, c^{-1}b^{-1}cd, bef, cge, dfg, egf\rangle&\text{tidy up, spot that $c=d$}\\
&\cong \langle b,d,e,f,g \mid d^{-1}b^{-1}dd, bef, dge, dfg, egf\rangle&\text{remove $c$ generator}\\
&\cong \langle b,d,e,f,g \mid b^{-1}d, bef, dge, dfg, egf\rangle&\text{tidy up, spot that $b=d$}\\
&\cong \langle d,e,f,g \mid def, dge, dfg, egf\rangle&\text{remove $b$ generator}\\
&\cong \langle d,e,f,g \mid d=f^{-1}e^{-1}, dge, dfg, egf\rangle&\text{rearrange}\\
&\cong \langle e,f,g \mid f^{-1}e^{-1}ge, f^{-1}e^{-1}fg, egf\rangle&\text{remove $d$ generator}\\
&\cong \langle e,f,g \mid f^{-1}e^{-1}ge, e=fgf^{-1}, egf\rangle&\text{rearrange}\\
&\cong \langle f,g \mid f^{-1}(fgf^{-1})^{-1}g(fgf^{-1}), fgf^{-1}gf\rangle&\text{remove $e$ generator}\\
&\cong \langle f,g \mid g^{-1}f^{-1}gfgf^{-1}, fgf^{-1}gf\rangle&\text{tidy up}
\end{align*}

---

However, $G$ has no index-two subgroup. To see this, recall that such a subgroup is normal so we can consider the quotient group $G/H$, which is cyclic of order two. As $G/H$ is abelian, the map from $G\twoheadrightarrow G/H$ factors through the maximal abelian quotient of $G$, called the abelianisation $G^{ab}$ of $G$, so factors through the map $G\twoheadrightarrow G^{ab}$. So lets first abelianise $G$:
\begin{align*}
G^{ab}&\cong \langle f,g \mid g^{-1}f^{-1}gfgf^{-1}, fgf^{-1}gf, [g, f]\rangle\\
&\cong \langle f,g \mid gf^{-1}, g^2f, [g, f]\rangle\\
&\cong \langle g \mid g^3\rangle&\text{remove $f$ generator}\\
\end{align*}
Hence, every abelian quotient of $G$ is a quotient of the cyclic group of order $3$. Hence, $G$ does not have an index $2$ subgroup (but it *does* have an index $3$ subgroup).

Comment: Thank you.

So if G is not 3-generated, can I ask if I can be three generated and if we get a normal subgroup from that?

Comment: @ChrisG $G$ is $3$-generated - just take $g, f$ and any other generator. Changing the generators does not change the possible normal subgroups - subgroups are group invariants and are not changed by changing generators.